# Python modifying a dictionary with a function call

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my code.  I am trying to construct a list of names to create a bunch of defaultdicts.  Then I want to modify these default dicts by calling a function.
Having problems as you can see in the comments.

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                             

from collections import defaultdict

class Stats(object):
    def __init__(self, name, namedict):
        self.name = name
        self.namedict = namedict
    def update_stats(self, playerdict):
    self.playerdict = playerdict
        playerdict['HR'] += 1
        return(playerdict)


l = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for x in l:
    d = x + 'dict'   # trying to make a list of dict names
    print "Name is",d   # it is a string so far
    d = defaultdict(int)  # now it is a dict but what is its name?
    print d  # i have a structure here but don't know its name

stats = Stats('stats',d)

#   next test code block does not work   

#for k,v in adict.iteritems():   # adict not defined!                                                         
#    print k,v                                                                                                

# next code block does not work either
for y in l:
    dictname = y + 'dict'
    dictname = stats.update_stats(**dictname)    
# it thinks dictname is a        String 
# in general what is the right way to pass in a dictionary 
# and get it back in a modified state?
```

Comment: i dont see any dictionary defined in your code  adict = {} ? maybe this can get you started http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: The confusion is that in other languages, which are more lax, it is OK to construct strings inside of loops then make them the new dictionary names.  I was trying to, inside a loop, create the strings  'adict', 'bdict' and so forth and both assign them to a new dict while at the same time initializing that new dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you're confused about variable use.  "name" is not an attribute of a dictionary; they have keys and associated values.  You can make a variable refer to a dictionary, but this property is not inherent to the dictionary.

I gather that you want to create new dictionaries, refered to by variables named **adict**, **bdict**, and **cdict**.  To do this, you'll need something like

```
adict = defaultdict(int)
bdict = defaultdict(int)
cdict = defaultdict(int)
```

If you want to handle them in a loop, then you'll need list whose elements are dictionaries:

```
dict_shelf = []
for i in range(3):
   dict_shelf.append(defaultdict(int))
```

The three dictionaries are now dict_shelf[0], dict_shelf[1], and dict_shelf[2].

Does this handle your problem?

Comment: Thank you, a list of dictionaries worked.

Comment: Sure.  Remember to "accept" an answer at some point: this lets SO properly retire the question.  If you like parts of both answers, you can even write a third answer yourself and accept *that* one.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is some misunderstanding which requires clarification.

When you write:

```
d = x + 'dict'
```

you assign label `d` to a string (e.g. `'adict'`)

Then, with:

```
d = defaultdict(int)
```

you **reassign** label `d` to some `defaultdict`. It is no longer assigned to the string.

Then you try to access label `adict` - which has never been defined (assigned). Of courze, there was a string `'adict'`, but it was a string (object in memory), not a label.